# Finding the point on an ellipse most distant from a given line

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

$\mathrm C$onsider an ellipse with the origin as its centre, i.e., of the type
$$\frac {x^2} {a^2} + \frac {y^2} {b^2} = 1$$
and a line joining two points on the ellipse.

$\mathrm T$he problem is to find the point, say, $\mathrm P (h, k)$, on the ellipse, furthest from this line.

I took the points as $ P(a \cos\theta, b \sin\theta), Q(a\cos\phi, b\sin\phi)$.
To solve this, I tried to use the formula for perpendicular distance of a point from a line, which is $$\frac{|Ah + Bk + C|} {\sqrt {A^2 + B^2}}$$
For distance to be maximum, $Ah + Bk+  C$ must be maximum.
Now, the equation to the line can be written in the form:
$$y -  b\sin\phi = \frac {b\sin\theta - b\sin\phi} {a\cos\theta - a\cos\phi} (x - a\cos\phi). $$
On simplifying, we can try to find the maximum of $Ah + Bk + C$. 
When this didn't work,I tried other, similar methods. I still haven't got anything useful, though.

Comment: Note that at the farthest point, the tangent line to the ellipse will be parallel to the line itself, so all you need to do is find the point(s) on the ellipse with the same slope as the line.

Comment: @VictorLiu Well, thanks, I've got my answer now. But, how can I _prove_ that the point at which the tangent is parallel to the given line is furthest?

Comment: @ABajaj, it would be interesting to see your answer. If you've not used Victor's suggestion, then your answer should imply it.

Comment: @SimonS Sorry, I have used Victor's suggestion, and I certainly didn't mean to imply otherwise. I just need to prove that the property he stated is true.

Comment: The distance line segment is perpendicular to the original line segment. Drawing a diagram it is 'obvious' that that distance is maximal when it also perpendicular to the tangent line $T$ at the point on the ellipse at maximal distance. All other distance line segments intersect the ellipse before they intersect $T$. Writing out an analytic argument is a pain, but if you really want to, I'm sure it can be done with calculus.