# The point on a conic furthest from a given line

Tags: geometry

To solve the problem of finding the point on an ellipse furthest from a given line:
[Finding the point on an ellipse most distant from a given line](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1053218/finding-the-point-on-an-ellipse-most-distant-from-a-given-line),
I was given the suggestion to use the fact that the tangent at the point on a conic most distant from a line, is parallel to the line. However, I have no idea how to prove this.

I'm interested in any proof, though I suspect that one which doesn't use differentiation is going to be quite difficult.

Comment: I'd also be grateful for the appropriate tags other than 'geometry'.

Comment: What does prove mean? Draw an ellipse, and a line  $\ell$ preferably meeting the ellipse. Imagine moving the line parallel to itself until it is about to leave the ellipse. There yoou have tangency, and maximum distance. (Note that there may be two candidates.)

Comment: But what if the line doesn't meet the ellipse; or, rather, meets it in two points. By prove, I mean, show that this is true for every line $l$ and every ellipse $E$.

Comment: The geometry is basically the same. Of course this is not a formal proof, it uses geometric intuition. Formally, we can set it up as a max/min problem.

Comment: @AndréNicolas Could you  please elaborate? Thanks a lot.

Comment: I am saying that the tangency part is geometrically obvious. It is not clear what kind of proof you want. It can be done analytically.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the set of all points a given distance away from your line. Obviously that set is a line. If you restrict this to points on the conic, you're essentially intersecting that line with the conic. For some lines, you have two points of intersection, and for some you have no (real) points of intersection. Between these two cases there is the limiting situation where the two points of intersection coincide, and the line joining them becomes a tangent. In other words, the tangent is the farthest you can go (for a chosen side of your original line) before the points of intersection vanish (resp. become complex), thus it corresponds to the maximal distance.